# Iterate through a file with a billions lines, output most occurrences of a line

Tags: perl, iteration

What is the best algorithm/approach to iterate through a file with numerous lines of Countries and printing out the country with the most occurrences?

Each line is a string and only contains a country name on each line.

Assume there could be 1 billion distinct countries.  (Countries is a bad example)

```
United States
Iran
India
United States
China
Iran
....
....
Canada //1 billionth line
```

Comment: Well if there are 1 billion DISTINCT countries, then the output of the most frequently occurring country will be ALL of those 1 billion distinct countries. :) Just saying...

Comment: Hence, the "there could"

Comment: Just saying if all the entries (countries) are DISTINCT there is no need to write any code. All would occur only once.

Comment: Yes, but you would have to somehow check if that was the case.

Comment: what OS?  if there are truly billions of distinct values, I would just `sort foo.dat|uniq -c|perl -walne'END{print $big_val} ($big_cnt,$big_val) = @F if ! $big_cnt || $big_cnt < $F[0]'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# Count the unique elements.
my %hash;
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    $hash{$_}++;
}

# Find the key with the largest value.
sub largest_value {
    my $hash = shift;

    my ($big_key, $big_val) = each %$hash;

    while (my ($key, $val) = each %$hash) {
        if ($val > $big_val) {
            $big_key = $key;
            $big_val = $val;
        }
    }

    return $big_key;
}

print largest_value(\%hash);
```

Comment: Reduced memory usage to 1/2 or less of the original.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a hash of integers. Although there are many lines, country names are limited in number so file size does not really matter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  $hash{$_}++;
}

my @sorted = sort { $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash;
print "$sorted[0]: $hash{$sorted[0]}\n";
```

Comment: +1 was what I was going to suggest.  You didn't answer the part about printing the country with the highest count, but that's kinda trivial.

Comment: I think printing the country with the highest is the most interesting part.  Do you think, sorting is the most optimized solution, especially with billion records??

Comment: Why not? There are fewer than 200 countries, and your hash will only contain no more than 200 counties. Sorting is trivial. However, Perl sorting is about O(Log O), so it might be quicker by a few miliseconds to simply search for the largest one in size.

Comment: If you just need the most frequent, finding the max is better. But the number of countries is limited so I don't think it makes a huge difference.

Comment: I should have used something other than countries.  Probably cities in the world would have been more accurate.

Comment: The input size matters, not constants. If you want to find the most frequent word or sentence then since it is dependent on the input size, max is most definitely better,

Comment: There are still way less than a billion cities.  If there really could be a billion distinct values, a hash is not going to cut it.

Comment: @DavidW., your `O(Log O)` confuses me, do you mean O(nlogn)?

Comment: @perreal Yup, your right. It should be O(n log n). College is just a hazy memory for me now. Actually, college was always pretty much a hazy memory. All I can really remember is that a lot of Doritos were involved.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $big_count = 0;
my @big_keys;

my %counts;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my $count = ++$counts{$_};

    if ($counts == $big_count) {
       push @big_keys, $_;
    }
    elsif ($count > $big_count) {
       $big_count = $count;
       @big_keys = $_;
    }
}

print(join(', ', @big_keys), "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash table: key is the country name, value is the number of occurrences.

Comment: Yes, then what is the best approach once you've created the hash?

Comment: Depend on what you want to do: You could keep "maxCountry" and "maxNum" as variables, and update as you go, or you could go through your hash at the end - remember you may have multiple countries with the same number, so scalar variable to hold the max country won't cut it...